# Buttons shrinking when adding them to onClick?

Tags: android, button, background-image, android-button

I added 3 buttons to a Linear Layout, and assign to them an onClick listener in my activity, Two of them shrink and wrap only the text included when running the code,

[image]

and the third one shrinks after clicking on it :

[image]

The buttons i'm using:

[image: active_button]

[image: inactive_button]

The code i'm using in XML :

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomButtons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/LivingRoom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ac_button_active"
                android:text="Living Room"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#00CCCC"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:tag="pressed" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/NoAC"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ac_button_inactive"
                android:text="No AC"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#00CCCC" 
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:tag="transparent"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/office"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ac_button_inactive"
                android:text="Office"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#00CCCC" 
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:tag="transparent"/>
```

Comment: are you modifying the Views at all in code?

Comment: is background of buttons is ColorDrawable? can you post @drawable/ac_button_inactive and background of all buttons?

Comment: are you using 9-patch images?

Comment: the size got bigger a little bit but still the same problem

Comment: the problem may be with background drawables you are using...

Answer (score 0):

when ever you use 9-patch images as background, they will be shrinked/adjusted to fit exactly to the Button size. Button size depends on the Text size and it's width.

so use paddings for Button to increase it's size along with margins if you need.

```
<Button
    .......
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" 
   ..........              />
```

Comment: gives me the same result

Comment: @MRefaat try using android:gravity="center" for Buttons.